In SpringBoot Html In Not acess or Not Showing other in webPage Value of that
This is my Index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Greeting Page</title>

</head>
<body>
Hello Home Page !!
<br>
<a href="result?data=500">Send data to server</a>
</body>
</html>

Here is another html file with name result.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>Your output is: <span th:text="${value}"></span>

</body>
</html>

This is my simple controller class with name First.java
package com.progrank.maven.MavenApp.Class;
import ch.qos.logback.core.model.Model;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class First {


    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String hello(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/result")
    public String index(String data,HttpSession session){
        System.out.println("Data:"+data);
        session.setAttribute("value:",data);
        return "result";
    }
}

In that after click on that link I am getting exception like
Send data to server  of that then they are redirect yo result page and data is alredy featching but they can not show in webpage they are showing a output is this :Your output is:${value}

Expexted Output is this :Your output is:500

You're setting data to the attribute value:, not value.

Will it show you a value after you fix a typo?

Here you are setting the session like "value:" but you fetched the value using "${value}" this is why value is not displayed.
Change From:
session.setAttribute("value:",data);

To:
session.setAttribute("value",data);

And now your code worked properly
